# Advantages and Disadvantages between using @FindBy vs WebDriver.findElement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm using a Cucumber and Selenium framework for UI automated tests and would like to know the differences between capturing WebElements using:

```
@FindBy (org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy)
```

vs

```
WebDriver.findElement(className/xpath)
```

My understanding (which may be flawed) is:

**@FindBy**

**Pro:** Stores reference to element so you only need to define it at the top of the class instead of everywhere it is used (using WebDriver.findElement)

**Con:** The value of the element needs to be "refreshed" before references using  `PageFactory.initElements(WebDriver, ClassName.class);` otherwise the element could be stale or a previous value from a page that has since refreshed

**WebDriver.findElement(className/xpath)**

**Pro:** You know that you are always getting the latest and current element from the className or xpath specified

**Con:** Needs to be defined everywhere used, code becomes messy when same className or xpath is defined frequently

Any help clarifying the differences here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct! You should read https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory again.

Answer (score 2):

`PageFactory` does not need to be refreshed before using references. It's a proxy. You should be able to google and find some references on the details of how it works but Selenium contributors recommend NOT using `PageFactory`.

`.findElement()` doesn't need to be defined everywhere used. You can just as easily define a `By` locator once at the top of the class and reuse that variable throughout the class.